# Laravel how to display only the attached patients of the users account on the frontend via ajax search by name or ID

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel

please help me, I have an AJAX search form in Laravel. It searches through the database 'patients', where they have a row 'assigned', where they are assigned to the ID of a user. The user searches through the AJAX search form, in order to find the patient. I want the user to be able to search and the results to show only the patients assigned to him, I don't want the user to be able to search and look through all the patients in the database. Here is what I tried so far, but it does not really work, please give me some ideas:

PatientController.php

```
function searchPatients(Request $request)
 {
    if($request->ajax())
    {
     $output = '';
     $query = $request->get('query');
     if($query != '')

     {

if(Auth::user() -> role  == 'user'){
      $data = DB::table('patients')
        ->where('assigned', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
}


        if(Auth::user() -> role == 'admin' || Auth::user() -> role == 'photostudio'){
            $data = DB::table('patients')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
        }

     }
     else
     {
      /*$data = DB::table('patients')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();*/


     }
     $total_row = $data->count();
     if($total_row > 0)
     {
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
       $output .= '

       <div class="col-md-12 text-center offset-md-9">

       <a href='.route("admin.patient", ["id" => $row->id]) .' style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">
   <div class="card-mt-3">
<div id="records-patients" class="records-patients">
       <div class="card-header">
         Пациент: '. $row -> name. '
       </div>

       <div class="card-body">
           <h3>Телефон:'.$row -> phone.'</h3>
           <h3>Имейл: '.  $row-> email.'</h3>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </a>
    </div>


   ';


      }
     }
     else
     {
      $output = '
      <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="5">Nothing found, please try again</td>
      </tr>
      ';
     }
     $data = array(
      'table_data'  => $output,
      'total_data'  => $total_row
     );

     echo json_encode($data);
    }
   }
```

AJAX search form and frontend

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){



     function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"{{ route('admin.patients.search') }}",
       method:'GET',
       data:{query:query},
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data)
       {
if(query !== ''){
            $('#patientsshow').html(data.table_data);

        $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
}
    }
      })
     }

     $(document).on('keyup', '#search-patients', function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
if(query !== ''){
        fetch_customer_data(query);
}
     });
    });
    </script>
```

```
<div class="row">

<div id="patientsshow">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define relationship between `User` and `Patient` models

```php
class User extends Model
{

    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Patient::class, 'assigned', 'id');
    }
}

class Patient extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then in the controller you can just get the patients for the currently logged in user using the relationship

```php
class PatientController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        //or
        $user = auth()->user();

        $patients = $user->isAdmin ? Patient::all() : $user->patients;

        //do other stuff with the collection and return response

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made this work by this one in PatientController.php

```
 if(Auth::user()-> role == 'user'){
            $data = Patient::where('assigned', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->get();
            }
```